# remove duplicate array in multiple jsons using python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

I have multiple JSON records like

```
{
    "Stat": "DEN",
    "Change": [{
            "From": "",
            "To": "DEN",
            "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000"
        },
        {
            "From": "",
            "To": "DEN",
            "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000"
        },
    ],
    "Date": 20200401
}
```

since Changes array has duplicates need to eliminate them it should be like

```
{
    "Stat": "DEN",
    "Change": [{
            "From": "",
            "To": "DEN",
            "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000"
        }
    ],
    "Date": 20200401
}
```

since it is an array am unable to use list,
I have a code like

```
doc['Changes'] = list(set(doc['Changes'])) if doc['Changes'] else []
```

It is working for items that are on the list
but I came to know its not a list it's an array it won't work,
can I get help for this, please

Comment: What exactly "its not a list it's an array"?

Comment: It is not a list like.     "Changes" : [1,2,3,4].    It is array like above

Comment: OK, but what? `doc['Changes']` is definitely a `list`.

Comment: It is not a list like. "Changes" : [1,2,3,4]. It is array like above

Comment: What do you mean by that? Perhaps you should clarify yourself with Python nomenclature. `type([1, 2, 3, 4])` gives `list`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, the actual problem for me is the above I mentioned in question is an array and if there are multiple duplicate array I need to make it as onr

Comment: yes thanks so much one final question if i have json like
Changes has 2 unique values(out of three 2 are duplicates)

{
 "Status": "CLO",
 "Changes": [{
   "From": "",
   "To": "ACT",
   "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000"
  },
  {
   "From": "",
   "To": "ACT",
   "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000"
  },
  {
   "From": "DEC",
   "To": "ACT",
   "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000"
  }
 ],
 "Date": 20200401
}

Comment: and once i apply this logic will the output be like this?

{
 "Status": "CLO",
 "Changes": [{
   "From": "",
   "To": "ACT",
   "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000"
  },
  {
   "From": "DEC",
   "To": "ACT",
   "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000"
  }
 ],
 "Date": 20200401
}

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicate keys by dictionary comprehension since the dictionary does not allow duplicate keys. I have set the standard for `To` because you have sent it two times at the same receiver.

```
{each['To']: each for each in doc['Changes']}.values()
```

Comment: If there are duplicates it need to correct to make one,if there are only single it should not get distrub....this will work right?

Comment: Yes it will work

Comment: Ok so it should be like
doc['Changes']  ={each['To']: each for each in doc['Changes']}.values().    Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you're correct

Comment: yes thanks so much one final question if i have json like Changes has 2 unique values(out of three 2 are duplicates) { "Status": "CLO", "Changes": [{ "From": "", "To": "ACT", "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000" }, { "From": "", "To": "ACT", "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000" }, { "From": "DEC", "To": "ACT", "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000" } ], "Date": 20200401 }

Comment: and once i apply this logic will the output be like this? { "Status": "CLO", "Changes": [{ "From": "", "To": "ACT", "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000" }, { "From": "DEC", "To": "ACT", "changeTimestamp": "20200325000000" } ], "Date": 20200401 }

Comment: @srmu you shouldn't change parameters very frequently. It will make confuse what actually you want. If your problem has a solution but needs another. please set another question .

Comment: Ok I have posted new question and reverted it back